# using Xpath to get a href from html

Tags: xpath, google-apps-script

First time posting here and newbie at Google apps. I am putting together a url in a spreadsheet for a linkedin company. example: http://www.linkedin.com/company/National-Renewable-Energy-Laboratory

Can I use =importXML from a google spreadsheet plus Xpath to get the website url that is listed on each company page.

I have gotten to a point where I can extract all the href's from the page and the link that I need is in that, but I just want the website url.

Here is what I am using so far:

```
=importXML(R2, "//*[@href]")
```

Here is a link to my spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AheVK6uxf6AvdHhILTFrR1k4Wl9tWW5OVWpRRUJKMlE

The code is in S2

Appreciate your response.

Comment: Can you give a few more details.

Comment: Are you using spreadsheet functions or Google Apps Script, or maybe both? If it helps, typically, you cannot call spreadsheet functions from GAS.

Answer (score 1):

`//*[@href]` matches elements that have href, not the href attributes themselves. Try `//@href` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's more complicated, but a good solution would be to use the [LinkedIn API](http://developer.linkedin.com/rest), which you can access using [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_urlfetchapp).